# Единственный маркер на карте (Google Maps API v3)

Tags: google-maps-api

В Google Maps API есть такая функция

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    // Здесь подставляем позицию; я знаю, но суть не в этом
    // и поэтому не стал писать всё
    position: position,
    map: map
});
```

Oна добавляет балуны на карту, но сколько нажал — столько и ставятся.

Как сделать, чтобы ставился один, при последующих нажатиях — другой, а предшествующий — исчезал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может логичнее тогда этот маркер просто переносить на новое место?

```
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(...));
```

Comment: Да вы правы это лучше! но я сейчас сделал так и эта функция не работает 
marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(...)); 
я буду очень благодарен если вы подскажете как исправить вот это

if(markerisset == 0){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map
   });
  markerisset=1;}
  else {
  marker.setPosition(position)
  }
здесь маркер ставится но потом не перемещается

Comment: видимо надо больше кода. но лучше сначала инициировать маркер вне `if`. `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: position, map: map }); if (markerisset == 0) {marker.setPosition(position1)} else {marker.setPosition(position2)}` либо просто `var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: position, map: map }); if (markerisset == 1) {marker.setPosition(position1)}`

Comment: вот это все от начала создания карты и маркера
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
settings);
 var markerisset = 0;
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
     ///if (typeof marker.setMap != 'undefined') {alert('a')};
  addMarker(e.latLng);
    });
 
 function addMarker(position) {
  //alert(typeof marker.setMap);
  var marker =0;
  if(markerisset == 0){
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map
   });
  markerisset=1;}
  else {
   
  marker.setPosition(position);
  }
 }
не работает ((

Comment: почему то текст не форматируется

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nskc47ck/ так надо?

Comment: Да! Спасибо Огромное!